# Azure File Share - How to mount to subdirectory?

Tags: azure-storage

I have a lot of File Shares (NOT Blob) which I usually mount like so:

```
net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name>
```

The thing is, I do not want to have to use a different drive letter for each File Share...

I tried doing this:

```
net use C:\data\<share-name> \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name>
```

but I just get an error:

> The network name cannot be found

How can I mount multiple shares to a single drive on Windows 10 server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. as Windows "Map network drive" itself works this way. It takes network location and map to a new Drive in your machine.

[image]